# How to make correctly autocomplete in React

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, forms, input

I want to make **autocomplete** input of cities in React. I have `json` file of cities ~15mb. How should I correctly implement it? Should I keep this `json` on client side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could make a request to the server on every keystroke but start the search after say 3 characters

e.g. searching for London

You would only make the first request after the user has typed in `Lon`

15mb seems a lot though, maybe you want to think of filtering this down beforehand so you request less countries back. e.g. make the user select a country beforehand so you only request cities in that country. so if they pick USA, then type in `Chi` it would only return cities in the `USA` starting with `Chi`

I don't think it's a good idea to pull the 15mb client side as that is a huge amount of data

Comment: I see, the JSON data is huge. Ss there any way to edit it fast, not manually?

Comment: what do you mean "edit it fast"? do you mean filter through it? if it's that big you either need to cut some out or apply techniques to minimize pulling that amount of data over a server

Comment: yes, i have a lot non useful data in json and cities not formatted correctly. I am not sure that I need to cut all datas manually.

Comment: you can filter the json to return just the city name or something

Comment: let me know if you can accept my answer or need any more help @frontMaster

Comment: your answer helped me, thanks. Do i need to close this question? I am new on stackoverflow

Comment: @frontMaster you should click the TICK next to the question and the UP ARROW. that will signal to other users that the ticket is closed